# groovy regex in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Due to a scripting error we have a number of Jenkins jobs ending with 'None' on our server. I want to delete them with a groovy script. In the jenkins script interface:

```
import jenkins.model.*

def matchedJobs = Jenkins.instance.items.findAll { job ->
  job.name =~ /.*None/
}

matchedJobs.each { job ->
    println job.name
    //job.delete()
}
```

This yields no results. I can still find the 'None' jobs via the Jenkins search textbox, so I know they are there.

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the code snippet I cribbed takes no account of folders. This script finds all jobs in all folders:

```
import jenkins.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.*
import hudson.model.*

import hudson.scm.*
import hudson.tasks.*
import com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.*


jen = Jenkins.instance

jen.getItems().each{
    if(it instanceof Folder){
        processFolder(it)
    }else{
        processJob(it)
    }
}

void processJob(Item job){
  if (job.name ==~ /.*None$/){
    println job.name
  }
}

void processFolder(Item folder){
    folder.getItems().each{
        if(it instanceof Folder){
            processFolder(it)
        }else{
            processJob(it)
        }
    }
}
```